# Why are my cakePHP Function not passing it variables to the InfoBip SMS Sending Api?

Tags: php, cakephp, infobip, infobip-api

I created this cakePHP function to send SMS through the infoBip Gateway system but it seems not to be working as the error code keeps giving me empty destination. **to=>null** This is their [documentation link](https://dev.infobip.com/docs/send-sms)

```
public function sendSMS($recipient, $sender, $message) {
   $url = 'https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single';
    $to = explode(',', $recipient);
    $data = ["to" => $to, "from" => $sender, "text" => $message];
    $postData = array("messages" => array($data)); //message to send to gateway
    // encoding object
    $postDataJson = json_encode($postData);
            $request = array('header' => array(
            'accept' => 'application/json',
            'content-type' => 'application/json',
            'authorization' => 'Basic #################'
    ));
    $response = $this->cakeSocket($url, $postDataJson, $request);
     pr($postDataJson);
   ($response->body());
    return $response->body();
    //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

See attached the variables I am sending and the error response I get from the gateway[image: variable and Error response from gateway]

Please advise is needed on what I am doing wrong as the system is not receiving my variables. Thanks. learning to use CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says:

```
{  
   "from":"InfoSMS",
   "to":"41793026727",
   "text":"My first Infobip SMS"
}
```

and you sending array `"to":["41793026727"]`

You explode `$recipient` to array `$to`, so try `"to" => $to[0],`

Comment: Thanks @Salines for the observation but I still get the same result even when I enter put it to send to just one contact instead of multiple contacts. e.g:  $to = "234XXXXXX";

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah It's not only the `to` that is wrong, you're also wrapping the data in another object and an array under the `messages` key, which is not allowed for [**the `/single` endpoint**](https://dev.infobip.com/docs/send-single-sms). Have a closer look at the example code from the docs. It's [**the _response_**](https://dev.infobip.com/docs/send-sms-response) that will have the results grouped under the `messages` key, _not_ the request, unless you'd use [**the `/multiple` endpoint**](https://dev.infobip.com/docs/send-multiple-sms).